# splitting whole number into different ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft

I have energy bill og 350 units.
my tariff is
0-100    Rs 3
101-200  Rs 4
201-400  Rs 5

How do I split350 units into three columns 0f 0-100,101-200,201,400

Comment: What have you tried so far?